# Making actions happen at the same time in JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, synchronous

I have a logo `div` parted by two `span`s, at the moment I am fading in the first and after that fading in the 2nd. Now I am experimenting to trigger three spans and would like to make three actions happen at the same time, fading in all three elements while moving them into position with the CSS attributes margin_left, margin-right and margin-top. The following function triggers all further actions to happen after the fade of the first span has been completed. Can anyone of you give me a hint how to trigger actions to happen at the same time?

```
<script>
$('#logo span').eq(0).fadeIn(10000, function(){
    //this is the callback function.
    //when the above fade completes, anything in here will run immediately after.
    $('#logo span').eq(1).fadeIn(5000);
    $('#logo span').animate({ 'margin-top': '-210' }, 'slow');
});</script>
```

Comment: Sorry if it's obvious, but what's .eq(0) ?

Comment: @AndrewWalters its gets the first span in his collection

Comment: O I see, so couldn't we just move all the calls into the same level instead of having two in a callback?

Comment: Giving them the same class name and applying fadeIn function will seal the deal.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you again folks for all your help you gave me here. I inserted a font-size animation which gives it a nice finishing touch. In case you need this once I thought like adding it as a final post and answer! Saludos!

```
<!-- targeting the first, second and third logo span (image logo) to be faded in right after another, being moved synchroniously, animating font-size and finally displayed in a opocity -->
    <script>
    var oldSize = parseFloat($("#logo span.movie").css('font-size'));     
    var newSize = oldSize  * 3.9;
    $('#logo span').eq(0).fadeIn(1000, function(){
    //this is the callback function.
    //when the above fade completes, anything in here will run immediately after.
    $('#logo span').eq(1).fadeIn(800);
            $('#logo span').eq(1).animate({ 'margin-left':'0' }, {duration:5000, queue: false});
        $('#logo span').eq(2).fadeIn(5000);
            $('#logo span').eq(2).animate({ 'margin-left':'0' }, {duration:5000, queue: false});
                    $('#logo span').eq(0).animate({opacity: 0.7}, {duration: 5000, queue: false});
                    $('#logo span').eq(1).animate({opacity: 0.6}, {duration: 9000, queue: false});
                    $('#logo span').eq(2).animate({opacity: 0.9}, {duration: 5000, queue: false});
                    $("#logo span").eq(2).animate({ fontSize: newSize}, {duration: 5000, queue: false});        

    });</script>
```

Comment: Just out of pure interest. Why has this been downvoted actually? Only curious.

Comment: This is *very* old, but I'm guessing the downvote is for "you used the ideas from the top answer, but did not mark it accepted"

Answer (score 1):

You really have two options.

The first option is to use `queue: false` with `animate` to have everything happen at once.  Any animation which is called with `queue: false` will begin immediately.

```
$('#logo span').eq(1).animate({opacity: 1}, {duration: 5000, queue: false}); 
$('#logo span').animate({ 'margin-top': '-210' }, {duration: 'slow', queue: false});
```

The other option, if the animations are of the same duration, is to animate them all in one call to `animate`.  In this way, both effects are considered a single animation and are carried out together.

```
$('#logo span').animate({ 
    'margin-top': '-210',
    opacity: 1
}, 'slow');
```

**EDIT:**

Another option if your animations start to get really complex would be to use multiple named queues.  This gives you the ability to have multiple separate animations at once while still keeping the ability to queue related animations.  A small example I threw together can be found here:

http://jsfiddle.net/5PuPT/

Notice how the position changes and the opacity changes act on independent queues.  This makes it so each related animation waits for other animations of its type to complete but will not wait for animations on a different queue.

This is definitely overkill if all you are animating is what you have in your question.  If you have a much more complex set of animations, this may be an approach to consider.

Comment: queue: false, right, I have heard of this recently, where exactely would I have to set up this parameter, at the bottom callback or in the main function?

Comment: Strangely this fades the first span while after it decreasing the transparency of the second but not moving it. Do I miss something completely or is there a conflict with the eq() parameter?

`<script>
$('#logo span').eq(0).fadeIn(10000, function(){
    //this is the callback function.
    //when the above fade completes, anything in here will run immediately after.
$('#logo span').eq(1).animate({opacity: 0.5}, {duration: 5000, queue: false}); 
$('#logo span').eq(1).animate({ 'margin-top': '-35' }, {duration: 'slow', queue: false});
});</script>`

Comment: Did the margin animation work before?  Could you possibly make a jsfiddle?

Comment: I am trying to figure that part out. Actually I use the display:none attribute in the span to hide it initially. First I thought this might cause the problem. But erasing it simply makes the div appear than fade according to the function but does not let move it. Hmm.. I will try this fiddle thing! Gracias for the input. A hard one for me!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/TPZWx/ this is the fiddle but it does not really serve as there is nothing actually happening. I am starting to think that there is something wrong with my absolute positioning of the div and the spans inside it but playing around did not lead me nowhere so far.

Answer (score 0):

Just give them all the same class name, then call them using that class.

`$('.myClass').fadeIn(5000,....etc`

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is, that the movement of avery span in an individual movement. I tried to do it this way but could just not make it happen!

Comment: Nevermind, I like the idea and also the input. I think queue false and animate is the way to go but I have a hard time combining the parameter with the animate function!

Comment: Well for queue false, for your situation, should be placed in the callback section on each animate that you want to happen all at once. Whether or not you put it on the main 10s animation doesn't matter unless there is an animation that happens before it.

Answer (score 0):

Thx to everyone posting here. This is what I finally came up with and got it working for me. Triggering two spans in an absolute positioned div, depending on the finish of a fadeIn of the first span. While setting display:none for the spans and defining a zero margin-left you can then define a positive or negative margin-left in the spans to have them fly in from right or left while at the same time fading them in.

Thx to everyone who made it happen. Have a nice day!

```
<script>
$('#logo span').eq(0).fadeIn(10000, function(){
    //this is the callback function.
    //when the above fade completes, anything in here will run immediately after.
    $('#logo span').eq(1).fadeIn(5000);
    $('#logo span').eq(1).animate({ 'margin-left':'0' }, {duration:8000, queue: false});
     $('#logo span').eq(2).fadeIn(5000);
    $('#logo span').eq(2).animate({ 'margin-left':'0' }, {duration:5000, queue: false});
});</script>
```